# How to Remove Value from Object Key

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of objects called `active_filters`. It contains a key called value which can contain one or more values (which are separated by commas if there are multiples).  I'm trying to remove a certain code from the value key using findIndex. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong...would appreciate any help. Thanks!

```
remove_code = "SFMR";
active_filters[0] = {id: "data-type", value: "SFAR,CFAR,IFAR,SFMR,FFAR,PDAR,MCMR,EDMR,CDMR,ECMR,EDAR,CDAR,MDMR", type: "filtered-out-by-car-type"};
```

**Code:**

```
var index = active_filters.findIndex(function(e) { return e.value.split(",").indexOf(remove_code) && e.id === _id });
if (index > -1)
    active_filters.splice(index, 1);
```

Comment: will `id` be always unique in your  `active_filters` array ?

Comment: Yes, always unique. I'd like to keep the active_filters.findIndex structure if possible. Thanks George!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate the array with [`Array.findIndex()`][1] to find the element by `id`. If the element was found, split the value by comma. Use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to remove the code, and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) back. Assign the result back to the value property.

```js
var remove_code = "SFMR";
var _id = 'data-type';
var active_filters = [{id: "data-type", value: "SFAR,CFAR,IFAR,SFMR,FFAR,PDAR,MCMR,EDMR,CDMR,ECMR,EDAR,CDAR,MDMR", type: "filtered-out-by-car-type"}];

var index = active_filters.findIndex(function(o) {
  return o.id === _id;
});

if(index !== -1) {
  active_filters[index].value = active_filters[index].value.split(',').filter(function(s) {
    return s !== remove_code;
  }).join();
}

console.log(active_filters);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following with `filter()`, `map()`, `indexOf()` and `splice()`:

```js
var remove_code = "SFMR";
var _id = "data-type";
var active_filters = [{id: "data-type", value: "SFAR,CFAR,IFAR,SFMR,FFAR,PDAR,MCMR,EDMR,CDMR,ECMR,EDAR,CDAR,MDMR", type: "filtered-out-by-car-type"}];

var active_filters = active_filters.filter(i => i.id==_id).map(function(e) { 
  var temp = e.value.split(",");
  var index = temp.indexOf(remove_code);
  temp.splice(index,1);
  e.value = temp.join();
  return e;
});
    
console.log(active_filters);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could find the index the slice around it and set that to the value. Create a function that takes in the characters that you want to remove then find the index of those characters. After that you can slice from 0 to the specified index, then from the `index + 5` (5 to include the comma) to finish out the remainder of the string. Here's an example of that:

```js
const remove_code = "SFMR";
let active_filters = [];
active_filters.push({id: "data-type", value: "SFAR,CFAR,IFAR,SFMR,FFAR,PDAR,MCMR,EDMR,CDMR,ECMR,EDAR,CDAR,MDMR", type: "filtered-out-by-car-type"});


function removeChars(chars){
  const index = active_filters[0].value.indexOf(remove_code);
  let newString;
  newString = active_filters[0].value.slice(0, index);
  newString += active_filters[0].value.slice(index+5);
  return newString;
}

active_filters[0].value = removeChars(remove_code);

console.log(active_filters[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to remove a certain code from the value key using findIndex.

You're splicing the entire array `active_filters`, what you need to do is split the filter's value and splice it according the `remove_code` values.  To accomplish that, make a reverse loop and for each match execute the function `splice`.

Finally, join the values again separating them with comma.

```js
var remove_code = "SFMR",
    _id = 'data-type',
    active_filters = [{id: "data-type", value: "SFAR,CFAR,IFAR,SFMR,FFAR,PDAR,MCMR,EDMR,CDMR,ECMR,EDAR,CDAR,MDMR", type: "filtered-out-by-car-type"}];

active_filters.forEach(function(f) {
  if (f.id === _id) {
    var values = f.value.split(','), 
        length = values.length;
        
    while (length--) if (values[length] === remove_code) values.splice(length, 1);
    f.value = values.join();
  }
});

console.log(active_filters);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://codepen.io/egomezr/pen/dmLLwP.js"></script>
```